# Bathroom light fixture stopped working, then started working again

Tags: light

6X 40W lightbulb fixture. Stopped working 5 days ago. Fan still works. Day 6 fixture decided to work again.Any thoughts?

Comment: First would check that all light bulbs are tight.  If they are, would need to cut power to fixture at breaker then make sure all wire connections are tight, screws and wire nuts, at fixture and switch.  Do this because loose connections can heat up and cause a fire.  Did weather change much recently?

Comment: I would be looking for a bad connection at a wire nut or switch,  you mention the fan is it on the same switch as the light if so I would check the connection to the fixture first.